# How can I use synchronize.js with node's fs.exists?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, fs, synchronize

Node's [fs.exists](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) function does not follow the usual callback The callback gets only an argument with either true or false, instead of the usual error and result.  Because of this, I can't figure out how to use it with sync.await.

Is there a simple way to use sync.await with functions that do not follow the normal node callback convention?

This code:

```
var alreadyExists = sync.await(fs.exists(fileName, sync.defer()));
```

results in the error:

> Error: done() invoked with non-Error: true

because sync.defer() got a boolean in place of an error.

NOTE: Yes, fs.exists will be deprecated in the future.  That is a different topic.

Comment: FYI, see the discussion [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) about how the use of `fs.exists()` is an anti-pattern that is fraught with concurrency issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [partial function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partial_Functions) from the deferred callback, where the `err` argument (the first one) is pre-filled as `null`:

```
var defer         = sync.defer();
var alreadyExists = sync.await(fs.exists(fileName, defer.bind(defer, null)));
```

Comment: That little snippet will take me a bit to digest, but thanks!